# Python3 write to console after subprocess.call

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, stdin

I am writing a script in Python3 that makes a subprocess.call, and that call requires that the user writes a password.
I want the script to call the subprocess and afterwards automatically write the password, but so far I've had no success.
I am executing it from a Linux machine, if it's any help.

I have tried with Popen and Pipe

`p = Popen("Command that when executed requires me to input a password", shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write(PASSWORD.encode("UTF-8"))`

This gives an error stating that the password could not be read (meaning at least it completes the process)

and also with normal subprocess.call

`subprocess.call(COMMAND)
sys.stdin.write(PASSWORD)`

In this case, it waits until I press ENTER and then it executes the next line.

Comment: Is python giving you any errors?

Comment: Not a python error per se.
It either executes only the first line and waits until I write something, and after I press Enter it writes the password (subprocess.call), or it says "Can't read Password".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo','PASSWORD'], stdout=PIPE)
subprocess.Popen("Command that when executed requires me to input a password", stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
```

first you echo something to pipe, which is used as input to second subprocess

Comment: It does execute all of the commands, but something goes wrong because the password is not rightly written, for it says "can't read Password".
I'll try debugging, because it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Password are not expected to be read from a file when they are asked interactively, but only from the terminal.

On Unix/Linux, it is common that programs asking for a password actually read from `/dev/tty` instead of standard input. A simple way to confirm it is to write:

```
echo password | path/to/command_asking_for_password
```

If it blocks waiting for the password, it is likely that the password is read from `/dev/tty`.

What can be done?

- read the docs. Some programs have special options to pass a password directly as a command line parameter, or to force the read from stdin
- use a pseudo-terminal. It is slightly more complex that a simple redirection and non portable outside the Linux/Unix world, but the slave part of the pty is seen by the program as its real `/dev/tty`.

  ```
  import pty
  import os
  import subprocess
  ...
  master, slave = pty.openpty()
  p = Popen("Command that when executed requires me to input a password", shell=True, stdin=slave)
  os.write(master, PASSWORD.encode("UTF-8"))
  ...
  p.wait()
  os.close(master)
  os.close(slave)
  ```